# I need to search two easy-ui datagrid in two tabs

Tags: datagrid

I used the following function but still I can't search the second datagrid in the second tab..

```
function doSearch(){
    $('#dg').datagrid('load',{
        date: $('#date').val(),
        unit_no: $('#unit_no').val(),
                        employee: $('#employee').val()
    });

    $('#dg').datagrid('reload');            
}
```

Comment: ask the question precisely

Comment: Please clarify what language and system this question relates to. There is not enough information for anyone to answer properly.